# How to display Hex dump - each char byte in EBCDIC and Hex values

Tags: python

I have a hex dump which I need to display in formatted display in another file.
In Python we can read byte as 1 Char i.e. 'C', Is there a library where we can read each byte as 'C1' and convert to Character 'A'to display?

HEX DUMP

```
C1C20300 D1D2D3F0 00000000 00000000
000042F9 F8F0F800 40404040 40404040
40404040 C3C4C5C6 C7C8C9D2 40404040
40404040 40D1C1E8 D1C1E840 40404040
40404040 40404040 40404040 40404040
40404040 40404040 40404040 E9E8F040
```

CHARS IN EBCDIC

```
A B 0300  I J K 0 00000000 00000000
000042 9  8 0 800                  
          C D E F  G H I K  
            J A Y  J A Y   

                            Z Y 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can surely go from the hex dump to a list of integers. (I assume the file is not too large; if it is, use `readline()` instead.)

```
dump = ''.join(open("dump").read().split())
raw = bytes(int(dump[i:i+2], 16) for i in range(0, len(dump), 2))
# b'\xc1\xc2\x03\x00\xd1\xd2\xd3\xf0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00B\xf9\xf8\xf0\xf8\x00@@@@@@@@@@@@\xc3\xc4\xc5\xc6\xc7\xc8\xc9\xd2@@@@@@@@@\xd1\xc1\xe8\xd1\xc1\xe8@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@\xe9\xe8\xf0@'
```

And, as a matter of fact, EDCDIC is known to Python as "cp500":

```
text = raw.decode("cp500")
#'AB\x03\x00JKL0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00â9808\x00            CDEFGHIK         JAYJAY                                 ZY0 '
```